# View too large to fit into drawing cache only when no hardware acceleration

Tags: android, caching, android-view

I have an EditView, which text is added to by the user. For some reason, turning OFF hardware acceleration via

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

and adding ~40 lines of text, makes all my text go invisible and my Logcat shows `W/View﹕ View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 8334080 bytes, only 8294400 available`

I do not encounter this issue with turning the hardware acceleration off via the activity, nor do I encounter this issue with hardware acceleration completely on.

I need hardware acceleration only on this view off for specific reasons - is there a way around this drawing cache issue?

Comment: Now I am interested in what kind of a scenario you would need a hardware acceleration on EditText? It's a static element that isn't moving around, rotating...

Comment: I do not. However specifically disabling hardware acceleration on this EditText only breaks the drawing cache.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/161165  look this issue. You can disable this in manifest:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why turning it off via ```myView.setlayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)``` doesn't work, when leaving hardware acceleration ON works fine, as well as disabling it for the whole app?

Comment: <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/> it will enable hardware acceleration for all application if this supported by device

Comment: Yes, I know that. However, as I stated in my OP, I need hardware acceleration OFF on this view, I can't have it on.